# Syntax for creating a yearly rate variable using panel data in stata

Tags: panel, stata

I have a panel dataset where `panel_county_id` is the individual id of a county and `year` is year (for two years - 2005 and 2009). I am trying to find the gdp per capita growth rate between the two years.

I used the following syntax, but the variables were all null.

```
bysort panel_county_id (year) : gen gdppc_r_2009 = (gdppc[2009] - gdppc[2005])/(gdppc[2005])
```

How can I fix the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subscripts are quite wrong.  After sorting, the observations you want are just 1 and 2 for the first and second observations in each panel.

```
bysort panel_county_id (year) : gen gdppc_r_2009 = (gdppc[2] - gdppc[1])/gdppc[1]
```

It's not an error to use subscripts that don't correspond to observations in the data, but the result will be missing values (Stata doesn't use the term "null" here).